# how to copy and delete data from multiple table of sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table like this: this Table name is Transaction_tbl. field like this:

```
transactid   Tbarcode     dtime

1            100          2013-04-16 14:15:47.243
2            101          2013-05-10 10:15:47.243
3            102          2014-02-20 02:15:48.000
```

in this table

```
 transactid   is primary key
```

I have one more Table like this:this Table Name is KHanger_tbl.field like this:

```
transactid   Hbarcode
1             21
2             22
3             23
```

in my KHanger_tbl this `transactid is the foregin key`

i want to move date range  <=2013-12-30 data from Transaction Table to another Table called Transaction2013..  (i mean data in the 2013)
the same time corresponding Khanger_table data need to move Table Called Khanger2013..
after that i want to delete 2013 data from Transaction_tbl table and delete corresponding data from Khanger_tbl Table also....
how i can do this? any help is very appreciable..Thanks..

Comment: If your foreign key is decorated with the on delete cascade then removing the rows from the parent will automatically delete the rows in child table. Regarding the copy of data, what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    create table Transaction2013
    as
    select * from Transaction_tbl
    where dtime <='2013-12-30' ;

   create table Khanger2013 as
    select * from Khanger_table 
    inner join Transaction_tbl
    on Transaction_tbl.transactid=Khanger_table.transactid
    and Transaction_tbl.dtime <='2013-12-30' ;

    delete from Transaction_tbl
    where dtime <='2013-12-30' ;

delete from Khanger_table 
where exists (select 1 from Khanger_table
inner join Transaction_tbl
on Transaction_tbl.transactid=Khanger_table.transactid
and Transaction_tbl.dtime <='2013-12-30') ;
```

Comment: showing error at this line delete from KHanger_tbl 
inner join Transaction_tbl...Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'.

Comment: instead of your second query i wrote query like this:select * into Khanger2013
 from KHanger_tbl 
inner join Transaction_tbl
on Transaction_tbl.transactID=KHanger_tbl.transactid
and Transaction_tbl.dtime <='2013-12-30'..but i am getting error:Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'transactID' in table 'Khanger2013' is specified more than once.

Comment: sir..if i give   insert into Transaction2013
    select * from Transaction_tbl
    where dtime <='2013-12-30' ; am getting error:Invalid object name 'Transaction2013'.

Comment: so i can give like this:select * into Transaction2013
from Transaction_tbl
where dtime <='2013-12-30'

Comment: i suppose to create New table while executing query

Comment: and am getting error while executing second query:Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'transactID' in table 'Khanger2013' is specified more than once.

Comment: you should have mentioned that. if you are going to use the newly created table as history tables then you have to write a MERGE statement for subsequent operations

Comment: ok..sorry for that..your edited query having one problem..while executing first query getting error:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: Syntax is for Oracle. Google what's the sql equivalent of "Create as"  statement

Comment: ok,,i got that...but while executing second query i am getting error like this:Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'transactID' in table 'Khanger2013' is specified more than once

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could do that by using the trigger,create the delete trigger for the table of Transaction_tbl, because you said that "the same time corresponding Khanger_table data need to move Table Called Khanger2013"

Answer (score 0):

CREATE Trigger [dbo].[trgTransaction_tblForMove] ON Transaction_tbl

FOR DELETE

AS

```
    if (select dtime from deleted)<='2013-12-30' begin
        insert into Transaction2013
            select * from deleted

        insert into Khanger2013
            select * from KHanger_tbl KH
                inner join deleted D on KH.transactid = D.transactid

        delete  KHanger_tbl     
        where   transactid  in (select transactid from deleted)
    end
```

Comment: I am sorry that the scripts is a little messy.Please copy all the contents and then format that.

Comment: i will check and let you know?

Comment: After create the trigger, then execute the sql:  delete from Transaction_tbl
    where dtime <='2013-12-30'

Comment: while executing your Trigger i got error:Incorrect syntax near 'trgTransaction_tblForMove'.

Comment: I don't know why, but I could not format the scripts well.Is it okay now?This is the first time for me to post, please forgive me.

Comment: it s oke... i have to execute your entire code same time?

Comment: after you have created the trigger, then just delete the data from the table of Transaction_tbl.

Comment: i try to delete Transaction_tbl like this:    delete from Transaction_tbl
    where dtime <='2013-12-30' ; but getting error:The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_DamagePicture_tbl_Transaction_tbl". The conflict occurred in database "Vallett", table "dbo.DamagePicture_tbl", column 'TransactID'.

Answer (score 0):

write query something like this:

```
select * into Transaction2013
    from Transaction_tbl
    where dtime <='2013-12-30'


    select k.transactid,k.tid,k.Requested,k.HBarcode,k.Reqloc,k.Delivered into Khanger2013
     from KHanger_tbl k
    inner join Transaction_tbl t
    on t.transactID=k.transactid
    where t.dtime <='2013-12-30'
```